# App icon in disabled state in ios 7

Tags: ipad, ios7, itunes

I have put my ipad application in itunes in ad hoc distribution and I have downloaded it successfully. But my app icon is in disable state and I am not able to open my application. When I try to open my application by clicking the app icon, a dialog appears with text "installing" with a progress-bar. My target api is 6 and I am running my app in ios 7. I have gone through this error when I updated to ios 7. Please suggest me a solution to rectify this error.

Comment: Did you try to completely remove and reinstall the App on the device? And "My target api is 6", does this mean your deployment target is iOS 6.0 or are you using the iOS SDK 6.0?

Comment: yes. I have completely uninstalled my app but still I face this problem. My deployment target is 6 and I am running ma app in ios 7

Answer (score 1):

Is your device added in your provisioning profile ? If not add the UDID of your device in your profile.

Comment: Afaik, you can't even install an AdHoc App, if the devices UDID is not in the provisioning profile.

Comment: If the UDID is not added then a dialog appears with text "installing" with a progress-bar

Comment: All the devices udid are added in my provisioning profile. Still i am facing this problem. I got this error after updating to ios 7. Any other solution.